# Get beforehand all cells positions of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need for some propose to get all cells positions of a UICollectionView , but the original values, - the values that the collectionView is intended for me. I am **moving** the cells during the scrolling to get some effect, so i have to bring them back to origin sometime, but i couldn't find a way to get the original values when i need them , tried this :

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if(![cells containsObject:cell])
    {
        [cells addObject:cell]; //add pointer to cell
        [cellsY addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cell.frame.origin.y]];//save also Y position 
        NSLog(@"%ld %f",cell.tag,cell.frame.origin.y);
    }
```

turns out that this is not being called for *every* cell, so my array of values does not contains all the values, but some of them .

How can i get beforehand, all the values that he intended for all future cells to come ?

**EDIT**

Turns out that it DOES go over all cells , but i have some mistake adding them to array .

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, a stupid one. This delegate being called for every cell . i just has to save values right:

```
 if([cells count]<cell.tag+1)
   {
       [cells addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:cell.frame]];

   }
```